# Why did java decided to check equality between records based on their types?

Tags: java, record

I have read about `record` in java (introduced in JDK 14).
I like the concept of value objects (as it was discussed a long time ago by many java gurus).
I wondered about the decision to assert the equality of 2 records by their type + their values.

Why did they introduce the `type` assertion?
My guts tell me that if 2 records have the same values, they should be equal because by definition the values are final and there is no behavior introduced the records.

Comment: What would it even *mean* for two records of different types to have "the same values"? How would you define that? And would the resulting behavior actually be useful, or would it just create weird bugs?

Comment: A record is a class as it extends [java.lang.Record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html). If two different classes had the same attribute types, would an instance of one class be equal to an instance of the other class if the attributes of both instances were equal?

Comment: My gut tells me that considering two records of different types to be equal would violate the principle of least surprise, but I don't think the question can be definitively answered unless someone unearths a discussion of the working group where this was discussed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a reasonable default implementation for a value type.

It is still possible to override `hashCode()` and [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) if you want a different behavior.

Ignoring the type makes it harder to ensure the symmetry and transitivity requirements for equals. That is not specific to records. The default implementation for [`Object.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is even stricter, requiring reference equality. For defining equality of instances of a value type, comparing the values is sufficient.

Comparing instances of distinct types where only one type overrides equals but the other doesn't is wrong as it is almost guaranteed to break symmetry and transitivity. If the default was to allow comparisons of unrelated types, these things would be harder to spot (e.g by tools like static analyzers pointing out 'unlikely equal' etc).

An alternative might have been to prohibit overriding `equals` for Record somehow, but that might also prevent some legitimate usecases.